# Javascript based slider not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

today i was working with a slider , the effects are like a fading ,
i can see the effects but the image not  , i mean i put everything in a div box and i add properties in css stylesheet but i only can see the div margins and the shadow moving but no image at all
Here is the javascript

```js
//intervalo tiempo cambio img slide, 5 segundos, se llama a la función "avanzaSlide()"
setInterval('avanzaSlide()', 5000);

//array con las clases para las diferentes imagenes
var arrayimages = new Array(".img4", ".img5", ".img6", ".img7", ".img8", ".img9", ".img10");

//variable que nos permitirá saber qué imagen se está mostrando
var contador = 0;

//hace un efecto fadeIn para mostrar una imagen
function mostrar(img) {
  $(img).ready(function() {
    $(arrayimages[contador]).fadeIn(1500);
  });
}

//hace un efecto fadeOut para ocultar una imagen
function ocultar(img) {
  $(img).ready(function() {
    $(arrayimages[contador]).fadeOut(1500);
  });
}

//función principal
function avanzaSlide() {
  //se oculta la imagen actual
  ocultar(arrayimages[contador]);
  //aumentamos el contador en una unidad
  contador = (contador + 1) % 3;
  //mostramos la nueva imagen
  mostrar(arrayimages[contador]);
}
```

```css
.proslider {
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 70%;
}

.proslider img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 540px;
  position: absolute;
}

.proslider .img5,
.img6 .img7 .img8 .img9 .img10 {
  display: none;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="proslider">
  <figure>
    <img class="img4" src="PROs/PR.jpg" alt="img4" />
    <img class="img5" src="PROs/PR2.jpg" alt="img5" />
    <img class="img6" src="PROs/PR.jpg" alt="img6" />
    <img class="img7" src="PROs/PR4.jpg" alt="img7" />
    <img class="img8" src="PROs/PR.jpg" alt="img8" />
    <img class="img9" src="PROs/PR6.jpg" alt="img9" />
    <img class="img10" src="PROs/P7.jpg" alt="img10" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

only thing i am seeing is a box , with an efect of moving but nothing else i tried changing resolution , but nothing .

Comment: .proslider .img5,  .img6 .img7 .img8 .img9 .img10 {display: none;} indicate the image should not display

Comment: thanks , what should i put over there?

Comment: It's wrong: `setInterval('avanzaSlide()',5000);`. Change for: `setInterval(avanzaSlide, 5000);`

Comment: what? i guess the problem is not in there , but i have changed the line and nothing happened after that , thanks anyway